# How can I add a custom button to the post editor toolbar?

Tags: theme-development

I'd like to add a button the the WordPress editor's toolbar. When clicked, I want to open a modal dialog (exactly like what you get when you click the "Paste from Word" icon).

This might be more than one question, so the first question I have is what code to I need to add to my theme's functions.php to place the button with a click event that opens a modal window similar to the Word dialog?

Comment: A search would have yielded [several similar questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=tinymce+button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial I've read  http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/how-to-make-shortcodes-user-friendly/
He as a great example and you cal also download the source files and get a better understanding

That's how I added a custom button to the tinymce editor in my [**plugin simple TOC**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-simple-toc/) which you can also download , look at the code and get an even better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

i followed this tutorial: http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/tinymce-plugin-wordpress/ also has sample code.